# Previous user login is replaced by recent/latest user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc project.The project is working amazingly on localhost.However when i upload the project on a server , i am facing some issues.I login from a machine it is getting logged in successfully.Then i try to login as another user it works.Now i go to previous user login and i refresh the page the second user login takes over the 1st user login.In general,the previous user login is replaced by recent/latest user login.I searched a lot about this issue but couldn't find anything.Please share some suggestions regarding this issue.

I have a controller named AuthenticateController which has the actions as 
Login and Logout.I have tried implementing session but no luck.Here is the code.Please help me with proper session implementation code if possible or if there are any changes i need to make in my code.It would be great if there is another way of achieving authentication with proper login logout and back button issue.Thanks in advance!!

```
public class AuthenticateController : Controller
{
    DBEntities entity = new DBEntities();

    public static int userid = 0;
    public static string getreference = string.Empty;

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(AuthenticateModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var check = entity.TblName.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == model.Password).ToList();
            if (check.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in check)
                {
                    GlobalVaribale.UserId = r.UserId;
                    //FullName
                    GlobalVaribale.UserName = r.FullName;
                    GlobalVaribale.UserAccessLevel = r.AccessLevel.Value;
                    GlobalVaribale.OrgId = r.OrganisationId.Value;
                    Session["UserId"] = r.UserId;
                    Session.Timeout = 10;

                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else  
            {
                TempData["Wrong"] = "Invalid Credentials";
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return View();
        }

    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session["UserId"] = null;
        Session.Abandon();
        GlobalVaribale.UserId = 0;
        GlobalVaribale.UserName = string.Empty;
        GlobalVaribale.UserAccessLevel = 0;
        GlobalVaribale.OrgId = 0;
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }


}
```

}

I have created a global folder in which i have a class named as GlobalVaribale.The code is given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TimeSheet.Global
{
public static class GlobalVaribale
{
    public static int UserId = 0;
    public static int OrgId = 0;
    public static int UserAccessLevel = 0;
    public static string UserName = string.Empty;

    public enum AccessLevel
    {
        admin = 1,
        management = 2,
        employee = 3,
        contractor = 4,
        superamin = 5
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please share some relevant code. Especially that code where it says `static ...`.

Comment: Hi, [ask] and [mcve] are great tool to help you formulate a question. Here we lack code.

Comment: Please share your code specially your cookie and authenticate method

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. One is that you are using `static` variables in a web context, meaning they'll be shared between all visitors. Don't do that.

Your bigger problem is this:

```
var check = entity.TblName.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == model.Password).ToList();
```

You're rolling your own authentication logic. Definitely don't do that. Start over, use ASP.NET Identity and don't bother writing your own login code, because you're doing it wrong and opening up your users to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @CodeCaster but i am still not clear with the static part.Could you provide some detailed information about it? https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster